# Rails: Should I use has_many :through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, associations

I'm trying to figure out how to best way to create associations for the following models:

- User
- Category
- Post
- Comments

Here are the requirements I'm trying to meet:

- A user can have many posts
- A post belongs to a user
- A post can have many comments
- A comment belongs to a post
- A post can belong to a category
- A user does NOT have many categories. 
  (The number of categories is fixed and the same for all users)
- A category can have many posts

In terms of routing, I'd like to be able to access a post within a certain category for a specific user. For example:

http://domain.com/users/1/categories/1/posts

Since there is no direct relationship between User and Category, I'm not quite sure how to best set up the associations. And I'm totally lost on how to configure the routes.

Here's what I have for my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :metric
  has_many :comments
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Is this a case where I should be using has_many :through relationships? Or something more complex like polymorphic associations? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be a very good idea to use :

```
User has_many :comments, :through => :posts
```

If you like, you can also get categories comments, by :

```
Category has_many :comments, :through => :posts
```

Remember that a through association is just a facility that allows you to do things like user.comments directly (and through is the way for the association to find the user comment that is referred to post model).

Comment: Thanks! Would I also need to do something similar with categories here? `User has_many :categories, :through => :posts` in order to configure the routes so that I can have `http://domain.com/users/1/categories/1/posts`?

Comment: No, the routes do not have anything to do with associations, no connection at all. A user does not really have categories, so this association would not be a good idea :)

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. I posted a separate question about the routing problem. Doing more experimentation now too. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5760162/rails-how-do-i-route-unassociated-resources

Comment: i gave an answer to that as well :)