# Rails: How do I route unassociated resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, associations

I have four models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :metric
  has_many :comments
end

class Comments < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :post
end
```

I'd like to be able to access a post within a certain category for a specific user. For example:

```
http://domain.com/users/1/categories/1/posts
```

Also I want to see a list of all categories if I visit:

```
http://domain.com/users/1/categories/
```

Since categories are fixed and the same for all users, User and Category don't have a direct association. Because of this, I'm not quite sure how to configure the routes.rb file to access posts within a category for a user. I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use nested resources to do that like :

```
resources :users do
  resources :categories
end
```

For more : http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources